# Diamond in Generics Java 1.7 - how to write this for Java Compiler in 1.6

Tags: java, generics

how can I write Java 1.7 code for a Java 1.6 compiler, where the diamond can not be used?

Example:

```
private ReplacableTree<E> convertToIntended(Tree<? extends E> from,ReplacableTree<E> to) {

    TreeIterator<? extends E> it = new TreeIterator<>(from.getRoot());

    while(it.hasNext()) {
        E e = it.next().getElem();
        to.add(e);
    }
    return to;
}


public class TreeIterator<E> implements TreeIter<Node<E>> {
....
}
```

It is not allowed to write...

```
TreeIterator<? extends E> it = new TreeIterator<?>(from.getRoot());
TreeIterator<? extends E> it = new TreeIterator<E>(from.getRoot());
TreeIterator<? extends E> it = new TreeIterator<? extends E>(from.getRoot());
```

Especially the third one is confusing for me. Why doesn't it work? I just want to read Elements from a Tree (which could be a subtype tree), and when puch each of it in a new Tree with Elements of type E.

Comment: The third one is syntactically correct, but I can't find out what the problem is without the signature of `getRoot()` and the `TreeIterator` constructor.

Comment: The third one is *not* syntactically correct. (Please don't post answers in comments.). I second the question about the signatures of `getRoot()` and the `TreeIterator` constructor.

Comment: `getRoot():Node<? extends E>` says eclipse

In Code:
`public abstract class Tree<E> {
 
 protected Node<E> root; // the root element of the tree
 
 /**
  * @return Returns an Element of Type E as Reference.
  */
 public Node<E> getRoot() {
  return root;
 }
}`

Comment: And the Tree Iterator Constructor:
 `TreeIterator(Node<E> node) {
  this.head = node;
  this.current = head;
  start = false;
 }`

Comment: @meriton Oh, right, you can't use wildcards when instantiating objects.

Comment: @Blackbam: now it's missing the definition of Node. Can you please provide everything needed to make all of the code (except the problematic line) compile? And you should edit your question, please don't post larger chunks of code in comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wildcard types are not permitted as type arguments in [class instance creation expressions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/expressions.html#15.9):

> It is a compile-time error if any of the type arguments used in a class instance creation expression are wildcard type arguments (§4.5.1).

so the first and third variants are not valid.

Variant 2 is invalid because the `TreeIterator<E>` constructor wants a `Node<E>`, but you give it a `Node<? extends E>`.

As for the solution, Java 5 and 6 did not have type inference for constructors, but do have type inference for methods, and in particular [capture conversion](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/conversions.html#5.1.10). The following ought to compile:

```
TreeIterator<? extends E> it = makeIterator(from.getRoot());
```

where

```
private <E> TreeIterator<E> makeIterator(Node<E> node) {
    return new TreeIterator<E>(node);
}
```

**Edit**: You asked in the comment:

> The contstructor parameter type for `TreeIterator` is `Node<E>`. The constructor parameter of `Node<E>` therefore is `E`. When writing variant two, eclipse says the following: The constructor `TreeIterator<E>(Node<capture#2-of ? extends E> )` is undefined What does that mean?

Being a wildcard type, the type `Node<? extends E>` represents a family of types. `Node<capture#2-of ? extends E>` refers to a specific type in that family. That distinction is irrelevant in this case. What matters is that `Node<? extends E>` is not a subtype of `Node<E>`, and hence you can't pass an instance of `Node<? extends E>` to a constructor expecting a `Node<E>`.

Comment: The contstructor parameter type for TreeIterator is Node<E>. The constructor parameter of Node<E> therefore is E.

When writing variant two, eclipse says the following: The constructor TreeIterator<E>(Node<capture#2-of ? extends E> ) is undefined

What does that mean?

Answer (score 1):

In short you don't write Java 7 code for a Java 6 compiler - you have to use the old, duplicative non-diamond syntax. And no, you can't specify a target of 1.6 with source 1.7, it won't work!

Answer (score 1):

meriton already explained it well. I just want to suggest that you could as well do it without the wildcard declaration:

```
TreeIterator<E> it = new TreeIterator<E>(from.getRoot());
```

Comment: That would require to change the method signature of convertToIntended to declare `from` as having type `Tree<E>`. We don't know whether the callers would still compile after that.

Comment: @meriton: Why do you think that it would require a change of the signature? I just tried a simple example that does the same conversion just with different classes `class Test<E> { List<E> test( Collection<? extends E> from ) { return new ArrayList<E>( from ); } }` and it compiles fine in Java 1.6.

Comment: The difference is that the constructor of ArrayList declares its argument to be of type `Collection<? extends E>`. It wouldn't work if the declared type was `Collection<E>`. The constructor of TreeIterator declares its argument to be of type `Node<E>`, not `Node<? extends E>`.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, `<>` means to just use the same type parameter as in the declaration to the left. But in this case, that declaration is a wildcard.

It doesn't make sense to make a constructor with a wildcard type parameter, `new TreeIterator<? extends E>(...)` because, usually, if you don't care what parameter to use, you should just pick *any* type that satisfies that bound; which could be `E`, or *any* subtype thereof.

However, in this case, that doesn't work because the constructor of `TreeIterator<E>` takes an object with the type parameter `<E>`. You didn't show the source code of `TreeIterator`, so I can't see what it does, but chances are that its bound is too strict. It could probably be refactored to make the type parameter `<? extends E>`.

But there are some cases where that is not possible. In such a case, you can still eliminate the need for the type parameter `E` through a "capture helper" (what meriton suggests above) to turn something which takes parameter `E` into something that takes a wildcard `? extends E`.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but in case someone stumbles on this, I would have thought the most obvious way of writing it would have been:

```
private <U extends E> ReplaceableTree<E> convertToIntended(Tree<U> from, ReplaceableTree<E> to)
{
    TreeIterator<U> it = new TreeIterator<U>(from.getRoot());

    while(it.hasNext())
    {
        E e = it.next().getElem();
        to.add(e);
    }

    return to;
}
```

I don't think such a change would break existing code as the type constraints are the same from the existing signature to this one.